# Delete Azure IoT Hub messages being used by Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have an Azure Function with IoT Hub as trigger. I disabled the Azure Function a few days ago. And now that I am enabling it, it runs the IoT messages that it missed (around 1000+ of them). I would like to ignore all of those messages and just run it with the new messages coming in.

How do I delete all the previous IoT messages?

Comment: You can use API to remove all of your message queue.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron there is no such API. The messages are in the Event Hub endpoint and will expire automatically. Until then, you cannot delete them

Answer (score 0):

First: The messages are in the Event Hub endpoint and will expire automatically after the set expiry time (*as Peter Bons correctly pointed out: It guarantees to keep the messages at least until the expiry time. Actual deletion will happen some time after that*). Until then, you cannot delete them.

The Function reads the messages from the EventHub-compatible endpoint. It uses checkpointing under the hood to mark the last message read (i.e. its offset). You can see this in the storage account that you associated in your Function settings.

To start reading only the latest messages, you would need to modify this checkpoint. You might be able to do this manually by editing the files on the storage account. But I'm not sure this will work. In this end, all this is abstracted away for you when using the IoT Hub / EventHub binding for Functions. Thus, this is not really supported. If you cannot just skip the messages in your code, you might need to implement E[vent Hub processor Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host) yourself - this gives you all the control you need.

Comment: *The messages are in the Event Hub endpoint and will expire automatically after the set expiry time.* -> not really. The messages are guaranteed to stay until the expiration date has passed. The underlying system may delete it after some time but it normally doesn't delete them straight away. I've seen messages being kept for weeks after the retention date.

Comment: That's in fact true. But in any case you cannot manually delete them.